# Unique and valuable gift for drinker?

Tags: specialty-beers, recommendations, whiskey, craft-beers

I want to give a close friend a unique and memorable liquor-related (his stipulation) gift. He's particularly fond of whiskey and beer but drinks most anything. What are some ideas, not necessarily limited to actual liquor? In the past I've given him special whiskey glasses, a $100 bottle of whiskey, a home brew kit, and a bottle of chartreuse. He's got a pewter stein he bought himself. Think big, between $100 and $200.

Comment: Hi eewanco, because the answers to this question are simply going to be a never-ending list of things you might buy, and no way to determine what might be a good or the "best" answer as individual tastes will vary, it's not a good fit for the StackExchange format.

Comment: What's his tipple of choice? My dad is fond of lots of different booze so I have gotten him a variety of gifts in the past. He was a big fan of [this wine purifier](https://ullowine.com/) which you can also buy the decanter along with. My next aim (will need to be a big birthday) is to get him one of [these, a wine saver so that you can pour out one glass at a time and store the wine again after](https://www.wineware.co.uk/coravin-model-one-grey-blue)

Answer (score 0):

While:

- this might not be the type of drink they like
- this was a numbered birthday present
- this website is in the UK

Nonetheless, it might spark off some ideas: https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/p/18434/grahams-40-year-old-tawny-port

It was his 40th birthday, so a 40 year old port with a custom engraved bottle. He's a Tolkein fan, so the inscription read: "Such an excellent and admirable hobbit"

Answer (score 0):

1. A wine cooler. It would be memorable if he doesn’t plan on getting one himself.
2. [VIP] tickets to a high-end wine/whisky tasting event.
3. Membership to the [Scotch Malt Whisky Society](https://www.smwsa.com/). Maybe you’d even be able to find a particular bottle (or two - given your price range) whose description memorializes some aspect/episode in your friendship.

Answer (score 0):

**Unique and valuable gift for drinker?**

The following suggestion I have already done as a gift. It is awesome.

It may not be the price that makes it valuable or unique. But a Crown Royal with a personalized label would definitely be an unique item to say the lest. And yes do not forget the custom bag(s).

For example:

[image: Crown Royal Northern Harvest]

Crown Royal Northern Harvest label goes for only $3.00

[image: CROWN ROYAL RESERVE BAG]

CROWN ROYAL RESERVE BAG goes for an  additional $9.95

Then of coarse you must buy your appropriate bottle of Crown Royal to go along with your label and/or customized bag.